# Mouse Click not Recognize in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, event-listener, jlist, jdialog

I have a Component I created that extends JTextField,
the component shows a list of items as you are typing for auto-complete.
You can move within the list using the arrow keys and press enter, or double click on an item on the list to select it,
and completed the text in the TextField.

If I use the component in a Frame it works perfectly but when I use it in a JDialog the double click on the list does not work. Any ideas?

Here is an extract of the code

```
public class CTextField extends JTextField implements FocusListener, DocumentListener, KeyListener {
    ...
    public CTextField () {
       ...
       
        final Window parent = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        popup = new JWindow(parent);
        popup.setType(Window.Type.POPUP);
        popup.setFocusableWindowState(false);
        popup.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        ListModel model = new ListModel();
        list = new JList(model);

        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                JList list = (JList) mouseEvent.getSource();
                if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    int index = list.locationToIndex(mouseEvent.getPoint());
                    if (index >= 0) {
                        String value = (String)list.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                        selectItem(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data for the list, or source it from inbuilt data (e.g. font names accessible to the JRE). 2) Sidebar: Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html) for a `JList`.

Comment: *the double click on the list does not work.* - I don't even see any logic for a double click. Check out [List Action](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) for a reusable class the might help.